# Slightly Different Take on Being a Ruby Newbie

Tags: ruby

I've been banging around with Peter Cooper's excellent book, as well as a few other resources in order to get a foothold in Ruby; now I'd like to go a step further. I'm wondering if I could reinforce what I've learnt by looking at code snippets/basic programs that are simple to follow but also educational for the pre-intermediate.

So, if anyone can recommend some examples that will help someone with a general grasp of syntax, but shows how to create or implement an idea, I would be very grateful. What I'm looking for is something that I can take apart and put back together again in order to get to grips with a concept.

I apologize if this all sounds a bit wooly, but I learn through repetition so the more examples the better. I've been using free online courses, to supplement my learning, but I'm looking for something I can play about with on Ruby when I don't have internet access.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and I look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to take a look at [RubyMonk site](http://rubymonk.com/). It's interactive ruby tutorials to learn Ruby intended for the beginners. It's free, so if you want to learn to code in Ruby it's a great place to start. Although it's a online course reminiscent of famous ['try ruby'](http://tryruby.org) I believe that would be helpful for you, because it contains a bunch of interesting and sometimes twisted examples and exercises for beginners. And yet another helpful resource - [this git repository](https://github.com/Habraruby) that contains various tasks and their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For improving knowledge what you got from courses or books, I've would recommend you these sites with set of interesting challenges: [rubyquiz](http://rubyquiz.com/), [puzzlenode](http://puzzlenode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through [rubykoans](http://rubykoans.com/)